# Read Rank from database and Increment it on C#

Tags: c#, mysql, mariadb

Am new to programming and C#. I have a program that reads RFID tags and saves the data in a MariaDb database, but anytime i close the app and restart, the rank also restarts from 1.Rather i want my code to read the database, select the maximum rank and then starts incrementing.

```
        public void AddEnregistrement_local(Enregistrement enregistrement)
    {
        Int32 max_rang = 0;
        try
        {

            // Ouverture de la connexion SQL

            // Création d'une commande SQL en fonction de l'objet connection
            MySqlCommand cmd_local = this.connection_local.CreateCommand();
            cmd_local.CommandText = @"SELECT rang_tra FROM traverser_essai WHERE rang_tra = (SELECT MAX( rang_tra ) FROM traverser_essai)";
            {
                {
                    this.connection_local.Open();
                    max_rang = Convert.ToInt32(cmd_local.ExecuteScalar());
                    max_rang++;
                    // Requête SQL         
                    cmd_local.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO traverser_essai (code_cse, code_ppa, code_crr, temps_tra, rang_tra) VALUES (@code_cse, @code_ppa, @code_crr, @temps_tra, @max_rang)";
                    // utilisation de l'objet enregistrement passé en paramètre
                    cmd_local.Parameters.AddWithValue("@code_cse", enregistrement.code_cse);
                    cmd_local.Parameters.AddWithValue("@code_ppa", enregistrement.code_ppa);
                    cmd_local.Parameters.AddWithValue("@code_crr", enregistrement.code_crr);
                    cmd_local.Parameters.AddWithValue("@temps_tra", enregistrement.temps_tra);
                    cmd_local.Parameters.AddWithValue("@max_rang", enregistrement.max_rang);
                    // Exécution de la commande SQL
                    cmd_local.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    // Fermeture de la connexion
                    this.connection_local.Close();
                }
            }
        }
        catch
        {

        }
    }
```

Comment: I think you are using the wrong variable here `cmd_local.Parameters.AddWithValue("@max_rang", enregistrement.max_rang)` shouldn't you use `cmd_local.Parameters.AddWithValue("@max_rang", max_rang)` instead ?

Comment: Oh Yeah!! just changed it and it worked. Thank a lot @dbraillon

Comment: You are welcome, I just posted the answer so you can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are using the wrong variable here `cmd_local.Parameters.AddWithValue("@max_rang", enregistrement.max_rang)` you should use `cmd_local.Parameters.AddWithValue("@max_rang", max_rang)` instead.